# Collapse do Navbar não fecha ao ficar no tamanho mobile Bootstrap

Tags: css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando fazer um nav bar responsivo, porém ao deixá-lo em tamanho mobile, quando clico no "hambúrguer" ele abre e exibe os menus, porém nao fecha, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="<?php echo url_site; ?>">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/footer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.8.1/baguetteBox.min.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lc_lightbox.min.css">



    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- KIT DO FONT AWESOME-->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6da99f56e1.js"></script>

    <!--ICONES DO GOOGLE-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="corfundo">

    <header><img src="banner site.png" class="img-fluid ml-0"></header>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria-controls="conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Alterna navegação">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="conteudoNavbarSuportado">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(página atual)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ação</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Outra ação</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Algo mais aqui</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Desativado</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-label="Pesquisar">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Pra funcionar os scripts devem vir ao final do documento e não dentro do Head. Além disso vc está importando vários scripts, alguns repetidos e outros rm versões antigas, importe apenas um de cada na versão mais recente. E se vc já está importando o jQuery completo vc não precisa importar tb a versão Slim

Comment: @hugocsl Era isso mesmo, desculpas  obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Sem problemas amigo sucesso ai